# How to loop through keys in struct for SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I have done XCode a long time ago and now coming back to pick up SwiftUI. I am trying to render the data of a struct in a HStack.

The struct looks like this:

```
struct Product: Hashable, Codable{
    var column0: Int
    var column1: String
    var column2: String
    var column3: String
    var column4: String
}
```

Inside the view body there's something like this:

```
var pdt: Product
var body: some View {
        HStack {
             Text(pdt.column1)
             Text(pdt.column2)
        }
}
```

The above will work, but I didn't want to hardcode *column1* or *column2* because the number of columns will differ. How can I use *pdt* as a Dictionary and loop through the keys so that I can display all columns?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach (for this simple case) - you can reflect properties and map them to shown values (for custom/complex types it will require more efforts by idea should be clear).

```
var body: some View {
    let columnValues = Mirror(reflecting: pdt)
                          .children.map { "\($0.value)" }
    return HStack {
        ForEach(columnValues, id: \.self) { Text($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would happen if the variables in the struct are `optionals`? How can we unwrap them?